# How to start and stop Firebase performance traces from a singleton dictionary with DispatchQueue

Tags: swift, firebase, thread-safety, firebase-performance, dispatch-queue

I am in the process of implementing Firebase performance traces, so i made a shared instance and added a dictionary to hold them.
What i understand dictionaries are not thread safe and i need to add a dispatch queue to handle this.

How should i be using DispatchQueue to get the most accurate trace?
Or am I taking the wrong approach to measure traces?

```
import FirebasePerformance

class Tracing {
    static let shared = Tracing()
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "thread-safe-tracing")

    var traces = [String: Trace]()

    static func startTracing(name: String) {
        shared.queue.sync {
            if let trace = Performance.startTrace(name: name) {
                shared.traces[name] = trace
            }
        }
    }

    static func stop(name: String) {
        shared.queue.sync {
            if let trace = shared.traces[name] {
                trace.stop()
                shared.traces[name] = nil
            }
        }
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are tried with `synchronus` method please try with `Asynchronus` and let me know.